# Does the Plywood Around the Toilet Flange Need to be Replaced?

Tags: bathroom, toilet, flange

How do I tell if the plywood around this toilet flange needs to be replaced? As you can see in the lovely pic below, the wood is discolored. (The house is 50 yrs. old.) But, if I tap it with a screwdriver, it doesn't gouge. It's not mushy. Am I good to go?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the plywood is solid and not delaminated “can’t poke into the surface” you may be ok.  It would be better to check the underside also.
There is a sealer that even hardens damaged wood so it will pass home inspections and will protect undamaged wood.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't check the underside as this section of the house is on a slab. I'll google the rotted wood hardener.

Comment: In the end, I decided to gut it and put in new wood.